# generate latex document with generated code?

Tags: errors

Hi i generate my latex code but i run in Mitex it throw this error

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.1 {"rows_
           views":[[{"style":{"borders":"","font_style":{},"text_color":"","...

?
```

my code :

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Sr.No. & Paper Title & Article Type & Publishing Year & Published By \\ \hline
1 & A Review of Medical Image Watermarking Requirements for Teleradiology & Information Systems & 2013 & Hussain Nyeem \\ \hline
2 & Russia’s Cyber and Information Warfare & Information Systems & 9, November 2016 & Valeriy Akimenko and Keir Giles \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

when i run in mitex the error:

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7400 64-bit)
entering extended mode

```
(C:/Users/salman/Desktop/ttt.tgn
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \begin
          {table}[]
?
```

Comment: Welcome! That doesn't look like TeX code.

Comment: its a tng code btw i mean tng file output

Comment: put `\begin{verbatim}` before the code and `\end{verbatim}` after it so latex does not try to read it a slatex code.

Comment: it throw error undefined control sequence

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry David but I have not understood the title of the user for your question.

Comment: @usmankhan you are not giving many clues as to what your document looks like, what command you used to process it or what the error message was. That makes it hard to help without guessing, but I'll post a fuller example as an answer.

Comment: I would guess that you are using `pdftex` not `pdflatex` which is why `\begin` is not defined, but you can not start a latex document` with `\begin` you need to start with `\documentclass` as in my answer.

Comment: i generate this code from latex table generator online and then copy the generated code in mitex when run it throw this error.

Comment: Please re-edit your question, now the error that you are showing is completely unrelated to the input code that you are showing.

Comment: the latex table generator (most of which make very poor code) only makes a _fragment_ that you can paste into a docuemnt it does not make a complete document

Comment: is there any way to do this ?

Comment: In order to sucessfully compile the table code, add a documentclass and surround the table with a document environment `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Sr.No. & Paper Title & Article Type & Publishing Year & Published By \\ \hline
1 & A Review of Medical Image Watermarking Requirements for Teleradiology & Information Systems & 2013 & Hussain Nyeem \\ \hline
2 & Russia’s Cyber and Information Warfare & Information Systems & 9, November 2016 & Valeriy Akimenko and Keir Giles \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}`

Comment: However, please be aware that your table will most likely not be shown completely on the creacted page since it is too wide to fit into the width of the textblock. To overcome this, you might want to take a  look at the `tabularx` package and its `X` type column.

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  {article}
?

Comment: Use `pdflatex` instead of `pdftex`.

Comment: As I said quarter of an hour ago, you need to use pdflatex not pdftex

Answer (score 2):

You have not given many clues as to the intention of the document, but to show a block of code as source code not interpreted as latex markup you can use `verbatim` as below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
{"rows_ views":
    [[{"style":{"borders":"","font_style":{},"text_color":"","
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The updated example with the table is similar, but you need to format the columns so they fit:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
{"rows_ views":
    [[{"style":{"borders":"","font_style":{},"text_color":"","
\end{verbatim}


\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabular}{
@{}
|l||
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}|
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|
l|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.1cm}|
@{}
}
\hline
Sr.No. & Paper Title & Article Type & Publishing Year & Published By \\ \hline
1 & A Review of Medical Image Watermarking Requirements for Teleradiology & Information Systems & 2013 & Hussain Nyeem \\ \hline
2 & Russia’s Cyber and Information Warfare & Information Systems & 9, November 2016 & Valeriy Akimenko and Keir Giles \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: see i update my question